# 184mb RAM after rpi-update

Tags: raspbian

I have a revision B board. I am running Raspian 2012-12-16 and only 184mbs are allocated. I have successfully run *rpi-update* but after rebooting I still have 184mb ram. I followed the article [here](http://www.dingleberrypi.com/2012/10/tutorial-enable-512mb-ram-on-raspberry-pi-with-firmware-update) . What else should I try?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing and still dont know what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand it, your RPi (if you updated it successfully) should now have use of all 512mb's. For curiosity sake, maybe also run the following command. Which will make sure that our RPi is updated (NOTE: This will update all installed apps as well)

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Check this [guide](http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt#Memory), which says that you need to add the following line to your 
    /boot/config.txt
file.

```
gpu_mem_512
```

> GPU memory in megabyte for the 512MB Raspberry Pi. Ignored by the
>   256MB RP. Overrides gpu_mem. Max 448. Default not set.

Also have you tried running `sudo raspi-config` and seeing if you can adjust the memory split there? (I dont have a 512 RPi, but I remember someone saying that raspi-config knew how to tell the difference)

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with this as well and found out that [initially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications) the Model B shipped with 256MB of RAM.  [Here is a post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/2191) explaining how to see what your system came with.